# Android 6 Button View Problems in HTML - Email

Tags: android, html-email, android-6.0-marshmallow, litmus

Only on Android 6 all my Buttons looks different. Even in Outlook 10 the Buttons looks i expected. I don't understand that..Or is this a Litmus Bug?

Here ist my Button-Code Foundation Zurb Email):

```
 <table class="button small-float-center"
   style="Margin:0 0 16px 0;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0 0 16px 0;padding:0;
         text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:auto">

<tbody>
    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">

        <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;
                   color:#000;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;
                   hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">

            <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                        <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;background:#fff;
                                   border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#000;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;
                                   font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;letter-spacing:1px;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:1px 12px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;
                                   word-wrap:break-word">

                            <a href="#" style="Margin:0;border:0 solid #fff;border-radius:0;color:#000;display:inline-block;
                                               font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;
                                               padding:7px 5px 7px 5px;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">WEITERLESEN</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: you have line heights with out px after the value. Which android 6 is this under in litmus? (there is two of them)

Comment: Its Android 6.0. Not the Gmail App (Android) 6.0

Comment: Android 5.0 has been pushing everyone to Gmail app.

Comment: Which means there is only one email client for android 6.0 Devices? And this is the Gmail App?

Comment: There are different versions of the same gmail app on v6. If you still havent tested it on a gmail app (an actual device) then i suggest you do it. At times there are glitches in Litmus which i have seen specially for android os'.

Comment: On Android 6 Gmail-App in Litmus everything looks as expected..I will check my email on an actual Anroid-Device.